# how to run grais, some kind of python program?

Tags: python

I built the gnu radio 3.7.9 from script here
https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGRFromSource
I built gr_ais
https://www.reddit.com/r/RTLSDR/comments/1mcikt/for_the_nautical_set_rtlsdr_with_grais_and_opencpn/
but following the instructions it can not find the command

Start gr-ais:
$ ais_rx -sosmocom -g35 -r250e3 > ais_pipe

This is what I get

scott@scott-P5QC:~$ ais_rx -sosmocom -g35 -r250e3 > ais_pipe
ais_rx: command not found
scott@scott-P5QC:~$ grais_rx -sosmocom -g35 -r250e3 > ais_pipe
grais_rx: command not found
scott@scott-P5QC:~$ ais_rx.py -h
ais_rx.py: command not found

Comment: I got this message gnuradio built

You should probably set your PYTHONPATH to:
 
     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
 
Using:
 
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
 
in your .bashrc or equivalent file prior to attempting to run
any Gnu Radio applications or Gnu Radio Companion.
*************************************************************
Done function pythonpath at: Tue Feb 2 11:27:17 EST 2016
Starting function extras at: Tue Feb 2 11:27:17 EST 2016
Done function extras at: Tue Feb 2 11:27:17 EST 2016
Done all functions at: Tue Feb 2 11:27:17 EST 2016
All Done

Comment: scott@scott-P5QC:~/gnuradio/gr-ais/apps$ ls
ais_rx  CMakeLists.txt
scott@scott-P5QC:~/gnuradio/gr-ais/apps$ ais_rx
ais_rx: command not found
scott@scott-P5QC:~/gnuradio/gr-ais/apps$ python ais_rx.py
python: can't open file 'ais_rx.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
scott@scott-P5QC:~/gnuradio/gr-ais/apps$ python ais_rx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ais_rx", line 6, in <module>
    import ais
ImportError: No module named ais
scott@scott-P5QC:~/gnuradio/gr-ais/apps$ 
it is a python script the file, why does this site have no line breaks, it is impossible to read

Comment: Because you are not supposed to write that much in comments. Add those details as edits to your question.